# PHP failed to open stream: Http request failed

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to connect this webiste: http://www.cit2.net

but when I use

```
file_get_contents("http://www.cit2.net")
```

I get this message:
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

I tried to use this code too:

```
  function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
  }
```

But then it just shows nothing.

Comment: Are you on a hosted server? They may have `url_fopen` and `curl` disabled. Check `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Most likely because they have disabled the scraping of their data.

Comment: And I can't bypass it?

Comment: This will probably be solved quite easily by sending a User-Agent header that sounds like a “real” browser …

Comment: Can you give example of one that looks "real"?

Comment: It took me approx 6 seconds to establish that the site you listed is not picky about what clients it talks to. (a lot less time than writing a comment here). The problem is on the machine where your code is running. Go read the curl pages in the manual - they describe how to capture and deal with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cbroe mentioned sending a "browsers" user-agent.

Try this:`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');`